# Javascript (ES6), destructure based off variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am wondering to see if there is a way to destructure objects in javascript with using a variable. Where as I was doing something like this in my function -

```
mutateTaxon(data) {
    const { content } = data;
    const { plp } = content || {};
    ...
```

This was working fine, however I need to expand this function based off another factor that can change if I need to use `data.content` (which it is using now) or `data.collection`. So I have another node on the `data` - which changes call to call. I am trying something like this -

```
mutateTaxon(data) {
    const match = lowerCase(data.taxonomy.name);
    const { match } = data;
    const { plp } = match || {};
```

Where that match variable would evaluate to either content or collection (as expected). This does not seem to work however, maybe it is not possible? I was thinking maybe the `match` var needed to be evaluated so I tried something like -

```
const { [[match]] } = data;
```

which also is not working. Maybe this is not possible, or I am approaching this wrong. I am wondering, is something like this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 const key = lowerCase(data.taxonomy.name);
 const match = data[key];
```

I dont think that object destructuring is useful here. But if you need that:

```
  const key = lowerCase(data.taxonomy.name);
  const {[key]: match} = data;
```

Comment: This is the desired result for sure, I am just curious if you can destructure based off a var. Thanks!

Comment: @ajmajmajma you can. `const { content } = data` is exactly that.

Comment: @ajmajmajma actually you can, just looked that up :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox no that's not what I mean. The payload returns `data.taxonomy.name` which is either content or collection. That being dynamic and destructing based on that. Otherwise i could just do `const { content, colleciton } = data` - see above answers

Comment: @ajmajmajma: See [Nina's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675823/javascript-es6-destructure-based-off-variable#comment86362675_49675823), the question is unclear.

Answer (score 8):

The destructuring syntax would, as Jonas W. said, be a bit more cumbersome than the bracket notation, but nonetheless, this is how you would do it:

```
mutateTaxon(data) {
  const key = lowerCase(data.taxonomy.name);
  const { [key]: { plp } = {} } = data;
```

#### Demo

```js
const foo = { bar: { plp: 'success' } }
const key = 'bar'
const { [key]: { plp } = {} } = foo

console.log(plp)
```

And to confirm that default parameter `= {}` works as expected:

```js
const foo = { }
const key = 'bar'
const { [key]: { plp } = {} } = foo

console.log(plp)
```

Comment: @JonasW. wow, didn't mean to steal the spotlight. I was actually about to delete my answer when I noticed you edited and then I got a flood of upvotes o.o;

Comment: people love snippets :), and nevermind, *zwei dumme ein gedanke* :)

Comment: I was about to ask about the feasibility of dynamic properties inside object literals, but then the OP is using destructuring.